# Simple implementation to get iterator of first word of each line of input

Tags: rust, iterator

I needed an iterator that streams the first alphabetic word of each line of an implementation of `Read`. This iterator:

- Returns an error if reading the input failed
- Returns an iterator of strings, each representing an alphabetic word
- ignores empty strings or first words containing characters other than `[a-zA-Z]`

I eventually ended up with the following implementation ([test here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a5068dbc2ba0144afd7d2e1c5246a326)):

```rust
fn get_first_words<'a>(r: &'a mut impl Read) -> impl Iterator<Item = Result<String>> + 'a {
    BufReader::new(r).lines().filter_map(|rline| {
        match rline.map(|line| {
            line.split_whitespace()
                .next()
                .filter(|word| word.chars().all(char::is_alphabetic))
                .map(&str::to_string)
        }) {
            Err(e) => Some(Err(e)),
            Ok(Some(w)) => Some(Ok(w)),
            Ok(None) => None,
        }
    })
}
```

This works fine but was more complex than I had expected. There are nested iterators in this implementation, and there was some type juggling in order to keep `Result` as the wrapping type while filtering on the contained values.

Could this have been written more simply, with less nested logic and with less type juggling?

Comment: For the line `"However, I'm not sure about the semantics."`, should your iterator skip the line or return `"not"`? From reading your explanation, I'd expect the latter, but your code does the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your `match` expression with [`Result::transpose()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.transpose). I would also suggest to split out the function returning the first word to make the code more readable. Finally, you don't need to accept `&'a mut impl Read` – simply accepting `impl Read` instead will work as well, since there is a [forwarding implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#impl-Read-14) that implements `Read` for `&mut impl Read`. Together, the simplified code could look like this:

```
fn first_word(s: String) -> Option<String> {
    s.split_whitespace()
        .next()
        .filter(|word| word.chars().all(char::is_alphabetic))
        .map(From::from)
}

fn get_first_words(r: impl Read) -> impl Iterator<Item = Result<String>> {
    BufReader::new(r)
        .lines()
        .filter_map(|line| line.map(first_word).transpose())
}
```

Edit: Using `impl Read` instead of `&mut impl Read` will result in mutable references being moved into the function rather than being implicitly reborrowed, so maybe it's not a good idea after all, since it will be confusing to remember to explicitly reborrow them where necessary.

Comment: Yes, that's it. There are so many iterators that return `Result`, this couldn't have been an uncommon situation. Thanks.